# Error while installing gem on Windows 8 - incompatible character encoding

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I need to set up environment to start writing cucumber tests on Windows 8. I installed ruby 2.1.5 (from windows installer on ruby-lang.org).
But when I wanted to install gems I faced encoding issue and got stuck.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:771:in `[]='
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:771:in `sender'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:525:in `block in fetch_resource'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:1096:in `block (3 levels) in resolv'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:1094:in `each'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:1094:in `block (2 levels) in resolv'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:1093:in `each'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:1093:in `block in resolv'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:1091:in `each'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:1091:in `resolv'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:520:in `fetch_resource'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:510:in `each_resource'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:491:in `getresource'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:92:in `api_endpoint'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source.rb:46:in `api_uri'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/source.rb:138:in `fetch_spec'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/api_specification.rb:76:in `spec'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:77:in `add_always_install'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:463:in `resolve_dependencies'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:238:in `install_gem'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:299:in `block in install_gems'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `each'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `install_gems'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:202:in `execute'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command.rb:307:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:168:in `process_args'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:138:in `run'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
    C:/jimi/Ruby21-x64/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone faced similar problems and found solution to it? Unluckily google wasn't helpful this time.

Comment: The best solution is to use unix-based OS, if you are going to use ruby as primary language

Comment: Does Gherkin (cucumber's parser) work on ruby 2.1.x?  The [documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin) says it supports 1.9.3-2.0.0.  You may want to try an older version of ruby.  YMMV.

Comment: I've tried installing ruby in the same way on my home PC (with windows 7) and there were no issues.

Comment: I have the same error on Windows 7 even when running `gem update --system`

Comment: Here's a temporary hotfix:
https://gist.github.com/headius/775696

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error on windows 7, I fixed the problem by doing the change below:

On the file **\lib\ruby\{version}\resolv.rb** I changed the line below:

```
request[0,2] = [id].pack('n')
```

To

```
request[0,2] = [id].pack('U')
```

FYI: On the version 2.4.0 the line number is 772.